# Creating a simple Unique Booking ID function

Tags: javascript

I need a special unique booking ID, which is easy for costumer to read-out over the phone.

It should be 5 characters long, and only use these letters:

```
var letters = "ABCDEFGHJKMNPQRSTUXY";
```

I found this function on stackoverflow but is having a hard time to get it to take chars from my letters and limit itself to 5 chars.

```
var uniqueId = function() {
  return Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 16);
};
```

Any help would be appreciated :-)

Comment: Why only 5? You're limiting yourself to a small number of "unique" orders. Unless you're expecting to stay small?

Comment: See [Create GUID / UUID in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/create-guid-uuid-in-javascript)

Comment: "small number" ehh.. try and do the math 20x20x20x20x20 :-D  if I have that many bookings I promise to expand it to 6 chars :-D

Comment: @evolutionxbox no the GUID is completely different from what I am trying to do

Comment: Check the duplicate I linked(Can I have my free-stay @Pattaya ? :D )

Comment: `[number of possible char]^[lenght of the generatet id]` - so you'll have 3.200.000 unique ID's... The 3.200.001'th ID won't be unique anymore... Take upper / lower into account if you wasnt to double it...

Comment: @Weedoze hahaha how did you know?? :-D    Great examples except none of them take in account that the same letter must not occur side by side. "ABCAB" is ok - "ABBCD" is not.

Comment: @daan.desmedt  3.2 mill bookings would put me in forbes top 400 richest heheh :-D

Comment: @torbenrudgaard never think too small! :p

Comment: @torbenrudgaard Edit your post to add this requirement. (I looked at your profile hehe)

Comment: @Weedoze if you ever get here write me on thaihome.co.uk and I will hook you up, in trade for some js lessons :-D

Comment: @torbenrudgaard I keep that in mind ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See function below, `uniqueId()` for a string of five characters (it is possible that the function could generate the same string multiple times, so it's not really unique):

```
function uniqueId(stringLength, possible)
{
  stringLength = stringLength || 5;
  possible = possible || "ABCDEFGHJKMNPQRSTUXY";
  var text = "";

  for(var i = 0; i < stringLength; i++) {
    var character = getCharacter(possible);
    while(text.length > 0 && character === text.substr(-1)) {
      character = getCharacter(possible);
    }
    text += character;
  }

  return text;
}

function getCharacter(possible) {
  return possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
}
```

Comment: is there a way to avoid two of the same letters side by side?   "ABCAB" is ok - "ABBCD" is not.

Comment: Yes, see update.

Comment: Perfect! - exactly what I need - Ganhammar you just made it into our global functions library :-)))  thanks.

Comment: @torbenrudgaard Does the loser get a free trip to Pattaya? :p

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```js
var letters = "ABCDEFGHJKMNPQRSTUXY";
var uniqueId = function() {
  var text = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    text += letters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length));
  }
  return text;
};
console.log(uniqueId());
```

`[number of possible char]^[lenght of the generatet id]` - so you'll have 3.200.000 unique ID's... The 3.200.001'th ID won't be unique anymore...

Take upper / lower cases into account if you want to double the amount of unique ID's...

```js
var letters = "ABCDEFGHJKMNPQRSTUXYabcdefghjkmnpqrstuxy";
    var uniqueId = function() {
      var text = "";
      for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        text += letters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length));
      }
      return text;
    };
    console.log(uniqueId());
```

Comment: is there a way to avoid two of the same letters side by side?   "ABCAB" is ok - "ABBCD" is not.

Comment: Something like this example would solve that - as demo only used AB letters - https://jsfiddle.net/zxos7456/1/ (now taking into account of checking the letter - checking the index could also be a possibility)

Answer (score 1):

Well some others just beat me, but here's an alternative that is fairly easy to read. It also incorporates not allowing 2 consecutive characters to be the same (as added in a later comment by the OP)

```
 function uniqueId()
 {
        var letters = "ABCDEFGHJKMNPQRSTUXY";
        var result="";
        while (result.length<5)
        {
            var rand_int = Math.floor((Math.random() * 19) + 1);
            var rand_chr= letters[rand_int];
            if (result.substr(-1, 1)!=rand_chr) result+=rand_chr;
        }
        return (result);
 }
```